# Determining number of layers in .mpk file and then enumerating it using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF?

Tags: layers, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I need to determine number of layers in a given .mpk file and then enumerate it using ArcGis Runtime SDK for WPF 10.2.

Can anyone provide me some link or code/snippet?

Answer (score 1):

```
   private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = myMap.Layers.Count;

            ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer dynLayer = myMap.Layers[0] as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer;
            List<string> plist = new List<string>();
            foreach(LayerInfo  layerinfo in dynLayer.Layers)
            {

                plist.Add(layerinfo.Name);

            }
        }
```